# Поиск по БД УСЛОВИЕ

Tags: c#, поиск

Ребята, как сделать сам поиск я знаю, запросы и все такое.
Помогите мне, возможно ли написать красивое условие если несколько разновидностей поиска?
или придется как я пока начал, это несколько(оч. много) else if.

```
            //По году
        else if (numericUpDownMonth.Value == 0 && textBoxArticle.Text.Equals("") && textBoxFIOSuspect.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select ID AS 'П/н', NumberCriminalCases AS '№ у/д' , Article AS 'Статья', DateIntination AS 'Дата возбуждения у/д', Subdivision AS 'Подразделение', FIOEmployee AS 'ФИО Сотрудника', NumberCRB AS '№ КУСП', DateCRB AS 'Дата КУСП', Fabula AS 'Фабула', FIOSuspect AS 'ФИО подозреваемого', LimitationDate AS 'Срок' From dbo.ListOfCriminalCases Where YEAR(DateCRB) = {0}", numericUpDownYear.Value), conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvArchive.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
            numericUpDownMonth.Value = 0;
            tabControlSearch.Visible = false;
        }
        //По месяцу
        else if (numericUpDownYear.Value == 0 && textBoxArticle.Text.Equals("") && textBoxFIOSuspect.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select ID AS 'П/н', NumberCriminalCases AS '№ у/д' , Article AS 'Статья', DateIntination AS 'Дата возбуждения у/д', Subdivision AS 'Подразделение', FIOEmployee AS 'ФИО Сотрудника', NumberCRB AS '№ КУСП', DateCRB AS 'Дата КУСП', Fabula AS 'Фабула', FIOSuspect AS 'ФИО подозреваемого', LimitationDate AS 'Срок' From dbo.ListOfCriminalCases Where Month(DateCRB) = {0}",numericUpDownMonth.Value), conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvArchive.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
            numericUpDownMonth.Value = 0;
            tabControlSearch.Visible = false;
        }
        //По году и месяцу
        else if(textBoxArticle.Text.Equals("") && textBoxFIOSuspect.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select ID AS 'П/н', NumberCriminalCases AS '№ у/д' , Article AS 'Статья', DateIntination AS 'Дата возбуждения у/д', Subdivision AS 'Подразделение', FIOEmployee AS 'ФИО Сотрудника', NumberCRB AS '№ КУСП', DateCRB AS 'Дата КУСП', Fabula AS 'Фабула', FIOSuspect AS 'ФИО подозреваемого', LimitationDate AS 'Срок' From dbo.ListOfCriminalCases Where YEAR(DateCRB) = {0} and Month(DateCRB) = {1}",  numericUpDownYear.Value, numericUpDownMonth.Value), conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvArchive.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();
            numericUpDownMonth.Value = 0;
            tabControlSearch.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (textBoxFIOSuspect.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select ID AS 'П/н', NumberCriminalCases AS '№ у/д' , Article AS 'Статья', DateIntination AS 'Дата возбуждения у/д', Subdivision AS 'Подразделение', FIOEmployee AS 'ФИО Сотрудника', NumberCRB AS '№ КУСП', DateCRB AS 'Дата КУСП', Fabula AS 'Фабула', FIOSuspect AS 'ФИО подозреваемого', LimitationDate AS 'Срок' From dbo.ListOfCriminalCases Where YEAR(DateCRB) = {0} and Month(DateCRB) = {1} and Article = '{2}'", numericUpDownYear.Value, numericUpDownMonth.Value,textBoxArticle.Text), conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            da.Fill(dt);
            dgvArchive.DataSource = dt;
            conn.Close();

            numericUpDownMonth.Value = 0;
            tabControlSearch.Visible = false;
        }
```

Это еще не конец, придется писать кучу условий пусто то или иное значение.

[image: Пример]
Попробую описать какие должны быть виды поиска

1. Поиск по году
2. Поиск только по месяцу
3. Году и Месяцу
4. Году и Статье
5. Году и ФИО
6. Месяцу и Статье
7. Месяцу и ФИО
8. Году, месяцу и ФИО
9. Году месяцу и Статье

Даже не знаю, все ли перечислил.

Надеюсь на светлые идеи.

Или я делаю правильно и иначе нельзя?

Можете кинуть свои варианты как вы бы сделали, может я переделаю.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У всех ваших запросов есть общая часть и её можно вынести в отдельную переменную.

Постоянная часть запроса:

```
Select
    ID AS 'П/н',
    NumberCriminalCases AS '№ у/д',
    Article AS 'Статья',
    DateIntination AS 'Дата возбуждения у/д',
    Subdivision AS 'Подразделение',
    FIOEmployee AS 'ФИО Сотрудника',
    NumberCRB AS '№ КУСП',
    DateCRB AS 'Дата КУСП',
    Fabula AS 'Фабула',
    FIOSuspect AS 'ФИО подозреваемого',
    LimitationDate AS 'Срок'
From dbo.ListOfCriminalCases 
Where 1 = 1
```

Переменная часть запроса для года:

```
and YEAR(DateCRB) = {0}
```

Переменная часть запроса для месяца:

```
and Month(DateCRB) = {0}
```

Для года и месяца одновременно:

```
and YEAR(DateCRB) = {0}
and Month(DateCRB) = {1}
```

И так далее.

Добавление тавтологического условия 1 = 1 позволяет прицеплять любые переменные части и избавиться от крупных кусков дубликатов кода. У вас появляется более компактный switch...case.

PS Вечно забываю, как этот приём в SQL запросах по-умному называется, может кто подскажет?

PPS И ещё. Внутри каждого if у вас однотипные куски кода - а это значит, что их можно вынести за пределы if и написать всего лишь один раз, а внутри if останется только `cmd =`. Ну и после этого заменить if на switch.

Образец для примера:

```
string query = "select ... where 1 = 1";
if(x == 1)
{
   query += "and year = 2017";
   execute(query);
}
if(x == 2)
{
   query += "and month = 01";
   execute(query);
}
```

можно заменить на:

```
string query = "select ... where 1 = 1";
if(x == 1)
{
   query += "and year = 2017";
}
if(x == 2)
{
   query += "and month = 01";
}
execute(query);
```

Логика понятна? У вас всегда внутри if идёт `conn.Open()` - почему нужно постоянно повторять эту строку, если можно было один раз ДО if написать?

Comment: Типо вместо всего запроса вводить переменную в которой будет описана большая часть запроса?

Comment: Можно по подробней замены if на switch.
Примерчик.

Comment: Что за **х**?
Я суть вроде понял, но от большого кол-ва if 'ов не избавится?

Comment: @ne0n замените if на switch. Внутри каждого case оставьте только выбор переменной части строки sql-запроса. Всё остальное легко выносится после оператора.

Comment: Спасибо за идеи. LIKE